# Invision Power Board error

Tags: php

i was running a network of wordpress, discourse,phpbb.... 
but recently i bought vbulletin and invision power board, i didn't face any problems with vbulletin but with invision i get an error when accessing any page the error can be bypassed by refreshing the page from 2 to 5 times and i'm in production mode, the problem started after i added some new plugins and apps (i really can't disable them) 
here's the error:

```html
SELECT tid FROM `ipstwg97forums_topics` AS `forums_topics` WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(start_date)) = MONTH(NOW()) AND tid IN (SELECT item_id FROM core_reputation_index WHERE app='forums' GROUP BY item_id ORDER BY COUNT(item_id) DESC) AND TRUE LIMIT 5
IPS\Db\Exception: Table 'ips.core_reputation_index' doesn't exist (1146)
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\IPS\system\Db\Select.php(371): IPS\_Db->preparedQuery('/*IPS\\plugins\\p...', Array, true)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\IPS\system\Db\Select.php(433): IPS\Db\_Select->runQuery()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\IPS\plugins\p9f8d35f32f\widgets\pec78f4281e.php(124): IPS\Db\_Select->rewind()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\IPS\plugins\p9f8d35f32f\widgets\pec78f4281e.php(105): IPS\plugins\p9f8d35f32f\widgets\_pec78f4281e->_getTopics()
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\IPS\system\Widget\Widget.php(762): IPS\plugins\p9f8d35f32f\widgets\_pec78f4281e->render()
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\IPS\uploads\template_21_94a9d7649fb9cdbfc784d3516e61a717_global.php(17393): IPS\_Widget->__toString()
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\IPS\system\Theme\SandboxedTemplate.php(56): IPS\Theme\Cache\class_core_front_global->widgetContainer('footer', 'horizontal')
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\IPS\uploads\template_21_94a9d7649fb9cdbfc784d3516e61a717_global.php(6342): IPS\Theme\_SandboxedTemplate->__call('widgetContainer', Array)
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\IPS\system\Theme\SandboxedTemplate.php(56): IPS\Theme\Cache\class_core_front_global->globalTemplate('1489ece0dbd3193...', '\n<div class='ip...', Array)
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\IPS\system\Dispatcher\Dispatcher.php(166): IPS\Theme\_SandboxedTemplate->__call('globalTemplate', Array)
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\IPS\init.php(447) : eval()'d code(36): IPS\_Dispatcher->finish()
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\IPS\system\Dispatcher\Standard.php(103): IPS\easypopup_hook_showPopup->finish()
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\IPS\system\Dispatcher\Front.php(556): IPS\Dispatcher\_Standard->finish()
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\IPS\system\Dispatcher\Dispatcher.php(148): IPS\Dispatcher\_Front->finish()
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\IPS\index.php(12): IPS\_Dispatcher->run()
#15 {main}
```

Ps: i really can't disable the new plugins if you have a way to solve this problem easily i'll appreciate it very much.
Thanks !
[home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NU7Bz.png)

[as you see the table already exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5fvn.png)

Comment: `Table 'ips.core_reputation_index' doesn't exist` <- the problem

Comment: what can i do i'm new to php

Comment: should i create one ? i'm using phpmyadmin

Comment: i actually looked in the database and i found the table  but why that error ?

Comment: did you found a table called `core_reputation_index` inside the `ips` database?

Comment: Unless this is in customization code that you've written, you should report the problem to Invision.

Comment: @Federkun yes i found it

Comment: @Barmar invision is not responding to my requests i need help here

Comment: It looks like you've renamed the table `forum_topics` to `ipstwg97forums_topics` in your DB. Maybe `core_reputation_index` should be `ipstwg97core_reputation_index` as well.

Comment: there is a ipstwg97core_reputation_index table indeed

Comment: are you sure you are using the correct database? maybe add a few screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: you can see screenshots

Comment: so, exists a table called `core_reputation_index` or `ipstwg97core_reputation_index`? or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the query references the table core_reputation_index buts it’s not that in the DB. Change the query to match the correct table or the table to match the query

Comment: can you guide me through this i'm really new to php

Comment: You need to edit ALL the queries in all the scripts to add `ipstwg97` before all the table names. Maybe there's an IPB configuration option where you can put this prefix and it will be done automatically.